# When can you say that $L^p(B) \subset L^p(A)$ if $A \subset B$?

Tags: integration

Good day,

As stated in the title, my question is: when can you say that $L^p(B) \subset L^p(A)$ if $A \subset B$?

Like I have $A \subset B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f \in L^p(B,\mathbb{R})$. Then

$$||f||_{L^p(A)}^p=\int_A |f(x)|^p dx \leq \int_B |f(x)|^p dx = ||f||_{L^p(B)}^p < \infty $$

since I just integrate over something "greater" and the integrand is non-negative, informally speaking. 
Is this already correct? Or do I need several assumptions on my sets? Like $A$ has to be compactly embedded in $B$ and so on.

Thanks a lot, 
Marvin

Comment: think about the functions, can they be meaningfully extended

Comment: A funtion, integrable on $B$, when restricted to $A$ is integrable on $A$.  I probably would not call it an inclusion $\subset$, though.  Maybe it should be considered a quotient $L^p(B)$ onto $L^p(A)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Ah, I get what you mean, thank you for your remark. Like $f \in L^p(B)$ then $\tilde{f} \in L^p(A)$ where $\tilde{f}=f|_A$. Otherwise it would really be a bit rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.

I assume that both sets are measurable, but that's rather obvious in that context, since you integrate over them.
To be more formal, as an intermediate step you can integrate over $B=A\cup(B\backslash A)$ and use the argument that 
$$\int_{B\backslash A} |f(x)|^p dx \geq 0 $$
It gets more interesting however, when you are changing not the set, but the [superscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings)...